# get dom from content in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

let say i have some divs in my page :

```
<div id="root">
   <div id="content1" v-html="content"></div>
   <div id="content2"></div>
   <div id="content3"></div>
</div>
```

and i write script :

```
cont myapp = new Vue({
  el:'#root'
  ,data:{'content':''}
  ,methods{
    get_content_dom:function(){
      return document.getElementById('id_from_content');
    }
  }
})
```

how to set method get_content_dom to find the dom where html content is attached,
because maybe sometime i want to move the html content to #content1 or #content2 or #content3.

any way to set the method to get the dom of html content?

=========================================================================

my point exactly is i need to know the dom when click event :

let say i have some divs in my page :

```
<div id="root">
   <div id="content1"></div>
   <div id="content2" v-click="fired"></div>
   <div id="content3"></div>
</div>
```

and i write script :

```
cont myapp = new Vue({
  el:'#root'
  ,data:{'content':''}
  ,methods{
    fired:function(){
      console.log('here is my dom and i can get current div id #content2');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: You might want to use Vue's `$refs` but I think you may be going about this the wrong way. Vue is best used as a data-driven framework, not DOM / content driven

Comment: Feels like an XY problem. You might be better off using the v-html binding for all three divs, with a method called with an argument that will then determine which div will receive a non-empty HTML string.

Comment: i updated my question because i need to do something special

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to handle events in a data-driven model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using the DOM to control content. Instead, drive the content with your data

```js
data: () => ({
  contents: ['content 1', 'content 2', 'content 3']
}),
methods: {
  fired (event, content, index) {
    console.log('Click event on DOM element', e.target)
    console.log('Click event on content index', index)
    console.log('Click event on content', content)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="(content, index) in contents"
       :id="`content${index + 1}`" 
       :key="index"
       @click="fired($event, content, index)"
       v-html="content"></div>
</div>
```